# print udates in telegram via telethon

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I am trying to print updates to my telegram acount . This is my code :

```
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash, update_workers=4)
client.connect()
from telethon.tl.types import UpdateShortMessage, PeerUser


def callback(update):
    print(1)
    print('I received', update)

client.add_update_handler(callback)
```

whats wrong ? nothing prints .

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest you add:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

So you can see what errors you are getting but can't yet see.

Significantly your program will end straight away because it never waits to receive any inbound messages. You will need to use something like client.loop.run_until_complete(somefunctionthattreadswater) at the end so that it hangs around until you press ctrl-C.